# Multiple drop down windows that auto-close when opening another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an example of what I'm working on at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/OfSilence/zFuUp/) so you can get an idea of what I'm working on looks like. I'm trying to find a way to make the drop-down that's opened auto close when opening another. All the solutions I find either keep anything from opening or opening & closing everything at the same time. Keep in mind on the final page their will be around 30 of these drop-downs.

Here is the *jquery* code as is.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".answer").hide();

        $(".question").click(function () {
            $(this).next(".answer").slideToggle(500);
        });
    });
```

The *html* is set up like this.

```
<p class="question">The question.</p>
<div class="answer">The answer.</div>
<p class="question">The question2.</p>
<div class="answer">The answer2.</div>
<p class="question">The question3.</p>
<div class="answer">The answer3.</div>
<p class="question">The question4.</p>
<div class="answer">The answer4.</div>
```

I'm very new to jquery & I'm doing my best here. Ive been working at this all day and only come asking for help as a last resort. If more info is needed Ill do my best to provide. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: There is a reason that the software does not let you just post a jsFiddle link. Instead of circumventing it with your little hack there, the question could be improved by showing your actual code here, and describing what you've tried in order to achieve your goal, as well as where you're actually stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close all open answers only if the clicked answer isn't visible: http://jsfiddle.net/zFuUp/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".answer").hide();
    //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
    $(".question").click(function() {
        // Check if we are closing us
        if( ! $(this).next('.answer').is(':visible') )
            $('.answer').slideUp(500)

        // Open us
        $(this).next(".answer").slideToggle(500);
    });
});
```